# Dart using jQuery date picker with initial parameters

Tags: dart, jquery-ui-datepicker, dart-js-interop

This works:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker']).callMethod('datepicker', []);
```

as in it shows a box with a calendar in it in the default form of mm/dd/yyyy but this doesn't change the format:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker']).callMethod('datepicker', [{'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'}]);
```

It works as above but still mm/dd/yyyy. What have I missed here?

Comment: Have you tried js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker']).callMethod('datepicker', ["option", 'dateFormat','dd-mm-yy']);?

Comment: @ZdeněkMlčoch sorry but this gives me error "Exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function" and acts as though no dateFormat is specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `List` or `Map` as parameter you have to use [new JsObject.jsify](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:js.JsObject#id_JsObject-jsify).

For your case:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker'])
    .callMethod('datepicker', [new JsObject.jsify({'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'})]);
```

Comment: sorry but this acts like no dateFormat is specified and defaults to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: It could be related to your usage of the datepicker. Please check the [datePicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). Particularly have you already initialized it ? In this case you have perhaps to use the `option` setter : `js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker']).callMethod('datepicker', ["option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy']);`

Comment: Yes you can set the dateFormat on the initialiser or afterwards. When this didn't work I tried both ways. The error in my other comment to Zdenek relates to the second callMethod function, which may shed some light on it.

Comment: I will give you this one as it appears I have to use 'format' and not 'dateFormat' but other than that your answer was correct. Thanks